# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_runtime() - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7

Tengo actualmente un sistema que me genera un PDF

Este es el código

```
protected function _dochecks()
{
    // Check mbstring overloading
    if(ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') & 2)
        $this->Error('mbstring overloading must be disabled');
    // Ensure runtime magic quotes are disabled
    if(get_magic_quotes_runtime())
        @set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
}
```

Y este es el error que me tira

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_runtime()
```

Como podría modificar mi código para quitar ese error y me genere el PDF

Comment: tengo PHP 8.1.2

Comment: Entiendo, pero lo que no se es como modificar esa función para que funcione con mi versión de PHP

Comment: Si es que fue removida entonces no hay modo de que te funcione, al menos no con la versión de PHP  que usas

Comment: **magic quotes** fue obsoleta en PHP 5.3 y removida en PHP 7, ese código es bastante antiguo. Sin embargo esas 2 últimas líneas de la función dicen: *¿Están las magic quotes activas?* entonces *desactivarlas*. Así que es probable que funcione bien si eliminas (o comentas) esas 2 líneas.

Comment: @aeportugal Si eso hice, solo comente esas líneas y funciono perfecto

Comment: Que bien que sirvió, lo pondré como respuesta para que quede la referencia.

Answer (score 1):

PHP eliminó el soporte para **magic quotes** entre en la versión 5.4 y 7.x, pero algunas funciones se mantenían vigentes, aunque obsoletas y siempre devolvían `false`, como [get_magic_quotes_runtime()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.get-magic-quotes-runtime.php). 
En PHP 8 [se eliminaron](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-runtime.php) definitivamente esas funciones.

```
    if(get_magic_quotes_runtime())
        @set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
```

El script no usa *magick quotes*, de hecho, el `if` consulta si estan activas, y si es así *desactivarlas*.
Entonces, la solución es eliminar o comentar esas 2 líneas.